# Solve checkmarx Spring ModelView Injection

Tags: spring, security, model-view-controller, checkmarx, sast

I have to solve this so called spring modelview injection in an old Spring MVC 2.5 application.

Checkmarx says
"The input processed by showForm in MyClass.java in line 112 is used to construct a ModelAndView object at MyClass.java in line 112".

This vulnerability is present whenever i use a param coming from the request to generate a dynamic modelview in any type of controller.

I have tried to sanitize the value or to get it from the database but it is still considered vulnerable.

Does anyone know how to solve it?
Thanks

```
protected ModelAndView showForm(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response, BindException errors) throws Exception {
         String code= ValidationUtility.sanitizeModelViewPath(request.getParameter("code"), String.class);
         String codeDB = myService.findCodeByCode(code);//Gets the param from the db
         String url = "redirect:/a/b.do?param=paramValue&param2=".concat(codeDB);
         return new ModelAndView(url);
}
```

Here is what i've tried to do

Comment: It would help to know the exact name of the vulnerability that is reported.

Comment: In the document it's called "Spring ModelView Injection"

Comment: I will have to look at the query, but you could try placing `"redirect:/a/b.do?param=paramValue&param2=".concat(codeDB)` directly in the `ModelAndView` as the ctor parameter.  My thought is that the query may be looking for `redirect:` in a static string but since you have it assigned to a variable it gets missed.  I could be wrong and this may not work. I'll try to look at this when I can find the query source.  In theory, this looks like a false-positive since it is using redirect.  Using `RedirectView` may also be an option if feasible.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but even if i add the parameters directly in the ModelAndView it gets considered as a vulnerability. Honestly i think it's a false positive too. RedirectView doens't exist in this version of spring so it's not an option